# @Html.Hidden get and set values razor mvc 4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

@foreach (var commentlist in Model.Comments.Where(x => x.CommentParentID == 0))
                    {

```
                    <div class="blog-comment">
                        <div class="comment-info">
                            <div class="user-info">
                                @if (commentlist.AllowViewingProfiles)
                                {
                                    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerProfile", new { id = commentlist.CustomerId })" class="username">@(commentlist.CustomerName)</a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="username">@(commentlist.CustomerName)</span>
                                }
                                <div class="avatar">
                                    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(commentlist.CustomerAvatarUrl))
                                    {
                                        <img src="@(commentlist.CustomerAvatarUrl)" class="avatar-img" title="avatar" alt="avatar" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            <div class="comment-time">
                                @T("Blog.Comments.CreatedOn"): <span class="stat-value">@commentlist.CreatedOn.ToString("g")</span>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <input type="submit" id="reply" class="button-1 blog-post-add-comment-button" onclick="return showHide();" />
                                    @Html.Hidden("CommentParentID",@commentlist.Id)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-body">
                                @Html.Raw(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(commentlist.CommentText, false, true, false, false, false, false))
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
}
```

I am using @Html.Hidden("CommentParentID",@commentlist.Id) to set value CommentParentID for ChildComment if any.

In  below action i want to pass CommentParentID as parameter.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Reply", "BlogCommentReply", "Blog", new { blogPostId = blogPostId, CommentParentID=CommentParentID,captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha }, null)
```

How i can retrieve this hidden field value in Controller?
Or How i can pass that value?

Answer (score 1):

> How i can retrieve this hidden field value in Controller?

By having your controller action an argument with the same name as your hidden field:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string[] commentParentID)
{

}
```

Notice that here I have used a collection because from what I can see you are putting those hidden fields inside a loop meaning that you will have multiple hidden elements with the same name POSTed to the server.

You could also use an array of integers of those Ids are integers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is through ajax something like this

Controller

```
 public void Method1(string val1, string val2)
        {
            ///do what you want with the values
        }
```

Page/Ajax call

```
 function PostData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/Method1',
                data: { val1: $('#hidden1').val(), val2: $('#hidden2').val()},
                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I am not using ajax anywhere.

Comment: how about form? It seems your HTML page has no form. Please take note that without submitting a Form or Posting using Ajax you cannot pass field values from page to a controller.